# How to create an array with references to other variables?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I'm trying to create an array (or collection) that can contain other variables that can be accessed or changed, and have the changes be reflected outside the array.

```
boolean autoTakeStepMode = false;
boolean[] settings = {autoTakeStepMode};
String[] settingsMessages = {"Enable auto-take-step mode (y/n)?"};
String response = "";
for (int i = 0; i < settingsMessages.length; i++) {
    response = ui.getYesNoResponse(settingsMessages[i]);
    if (response.equals("y"))
        settings[i] = true;
    else if (response.equals("n"))
        settings[i] = false;
}
```

When I try to access the autoTakeStepMode it is always equal to its default value, `false`.

Comment: You can't do this, basically. It's no different from setting `boolean x = autoTakeStepMode;` - if you change the value of `x`, that won't change the value of `autoTakeStepMode`.

Comment: Unlike C++, Java does not allow references to other variables.

Comment: you could use a map to store the booleans "by name"

Comment: This sounds line an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Back away from how you _think_ this should be solved, and explain what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: thats because you are using a primitive boolean type, if you change it to the wrapped class Boolean it is going to be a reference. So, if you change the value it would be reflected to every place where you are using this object. Any way, the map solutions it's better.

Comment: @MiguelResendiz Please explain how you would change the value of a `Boolean` (the wrapper type). Hint: You can't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I try to access the autoTakeStepMode it is always equal to its
>   default value, false

This is the actual behavior . If you want to update value of `autoTakeStepMode` then update it as well along with `settings[i]` .

```
for (int i = 0; i < settingsMessages.length; i++) {
    response = ui.getYesNoResponse(settingsMessages[i]);
    if (response.equals("y"))
        settings[i] = true;
    else if (response.equals("n"))
        settings[i] = false;

       autoTakeStepMode = settings[i];

}
```

Comment: I think this defeats the purpose of having an array containing boolean values for each setting when I have to explicitly assign `autoTakeStepMode` this way.

Answer (score 1):

The type should not be primitive type. If you want to change the variable autoTakeStepMode, you should wrap it with class.

```
public class AutoTakeStepMode {
     boolean isOpen;
}
```

Comment: Or use the Boolean class... it is a native wrap for boolean.

Comment: No, it works, just replace boolean to AutoTakeStepMode. Here's a blog about difference between primitive type and class type: http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/difference-between-a-primitive-type-and-a-class-type/

Comment: @MiguelResendiz Boolean is 'wrapped' but instances of it are not mutable, so it is no better for this Q.